# UPDATE SQL column based on values of another column. (It's not that simple)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a column with a value of a different column under certain circumstances. It's complicated. I've tried to figure this out on my own for a weeks now. (on and off)

Here is how it currently looks:
[image]

I Need a SQL statement that will look for the LotNo at OperationCode 1280 and assign it for all values with the same CastTID.

Here is what it should look like after
[image]

I would really appreciate any help! This is my first post, if iv'e left out anything important please let me know so that I can help you help me.

Comment: show your query as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join in your update statement to make this easier.

```
update t
set CastLotNo = t2.LotNo
from yourTable t
inner join yourTable t2 on t2.CastTID = t.CastTID and t2.OperationCode = 1280
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET `CastLotNo` = (SELECT `LotNo` FROM `MyTable` WHERE `OperationCode` = '1280' LIMIT 1) WHERE `CastTID` = (SELECT `CastTID` FROM `MyTable` WHERE `OperationCode` = '1280' LIMIT 1)
```

It seems like you could use something like that. I can't test this at the moment, so let me know if it needs tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT CastTID, LotNo
    FROM Table1
    WHERE OperationCode = 1280
)
UPDATE myTable T
SET CastLotNo = (SELECT C.LotNo as CastLotNo 
                 FROM cte C
                 WHERE C.CastTID = T.CastTID)
```